# Returning values from methods using NSRecursiveLock

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, macos, synchronization

I am transitioning some thread safety code from `@synchronized` to `NSRecursiveLock`.

Consider this code in which `myItemsArray` is an `NSMutableArray`:

```
- (NSUInteger) numberOfItems {
    @synchronized(self.myItemsArray) {
        return self.myItemsArray.count;
    }
}
```

I believe the following code is incorrect because the lock would never get unlocked:

```
- (NSUInteger) numberOfItems {
    [self.myRecursiveLock lock];
    return self.myItemsArray.count;
    [self.myRecursiveLock unlock];
}
```

So I'm using this approach instead:

```
- (NSUInteger) numberOfItems {
    [self.myRecursiveLock lock];
    NSUInteger itemCount = self.myItemsArray.count;
    [self.myRecursiveLock unlock];

    return itemCount;
}
```

However, I think this approach would break the thread safety, since another thread could add or remove an item *after* `-unlock` is called, but *before* `itemCount` is returned.

I'm not sure if I'm correct that the last approach isn't thread-safe, because I see this pattern in many widely used third-party libraries (for example, [`[AFHTTPRequestOperation -responseObject]`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.m#L83))

What is the correct way to return a value from a method synchronized using `NSRecursiveLock`?

Comment: Protecting `numberOfItems` can never ensure that the count is up-to-date. The array might be modified by another thread immediately after the method returns. It only prevents that two threads call the `count` method simultaneously.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for this comment, which helped me rethink my approach (it's much improved now.)  I would gladly accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protecting `numberOfItems` can never ensure that the count is up-to-date. The array might be modified by another thread immediately after the method returns. It only prevents that two threads call the `count` method simultaneously.